# Why does bathroom scales use half bridge load cell rather than 4 full bridge loadcell in parallel? Except for the price, is there any other reasons?

Tags: load-cell, calibration

I have been wondering why does bathroom scale uses 4 half bridge loadcell connected like this figure bellow rather than using 4 full bridge loadcell connected in parallel? Except for cheaper manufacturing price or half bridge loadcell is there any other reasons? For example, is it easier to calibrate for each loadcell corner?

Half bridge bathroom scale connection:
[image: 4 half bridge loadcell configuration from sparkFun]

From what I know, using 4 full bridge loadcell in parallel will average the sensed voltage from each load cell so we need to calibrate each corner using potentiometer to make sure they sense the same voltage at same load. Is it possible that this half bridge connection get rid of the necessity of calibrating each corner?

Comment: what accuracy  is required?

Comment: I need +-10 gram for 4 x 10kg loadcell

Comment: And also +-50 gram for 4x50kg loadcell

Comment: Why do you "need" ? are you building something different? In which case is your question really relevant?

Comment: Oh you mean you are asking for the loadcell specification from the manufacturer? it is 0.05% FS

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a single load cell, then full bridge is useful, so both sides track.

However if you are using four nominally identical cells, then you already have tracking, and half bridge does everything you need.

To the best of my knowledge, consumer grade scales do not calibrate each corner individually. They rely on the load cells having the same gain, which they nominally have being the same type, and simply add the four outputs together. If you trace the circuit, you will probably find that 'adding' is done by driving both inputs to the differential ADC from different cells, and inverting half of them.

While lack of individual calibration makes the scales less than perfect, they are adequate for consumer use, especially as with bathroom scales you tend to stand somewhere in the middle. Scientific or commercial scales would be likely to be individually calibrated.

If you are concerned about the accuracy, get a heavy weight and move the load to mostly one corner at a time. Take care that there is still some load on the other corners, as you do not want to get into non-linearity if the foot is close to lifting off the floor.

One part per thousand sounds very optimistic for 'bathroom' scales, whether for hysteresis, long term zero drift, or any other notion of accuracy.

Comment: I have done a test rig using 4 full bridge (50kg each) load cell in parallel, they supposedly identical with a bit of manufacturing error. But when I stand on the scale, the value is fluctuating and from what I have found it is because each corner gave different output from lack of calibration. So if I change the cell to half bridge load cell with the same rating will it give better result?

Comment: @shafiyyah fluctuating reading is due to noise, not lack of calibration - unless you mean position sensitive (fluctuating with position) rather than fluctuating (normally assumed to be with time when the single word is used). Half bridge is unlikely to be better than full bridge, just cheaper, so unlikely to give a better result. Clarify what you mean by 'fluctuating'.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I mean it is fluctuating with position